# как правильно объявлять функции?

Tags: c++

Допустим у нас 2 файла:1.cpp и 2.cpp
В 1 объявлена и определена функция foo();

```
int foo();
int foo(){
return 4;
}
```

А во втором функция main
И если мы в vs собираем проект и хотим использовать foo(); из main,то у нас ничего не получится и в файле 2.cpp нужно объявить функцию:

```
int foo();
```

Почему компилятор просто не может пройтись по всей программе и найти нужную функцию по сигнатуре,даже если она расположена в другом файле?Программа же все равно собирается в 1 pe.

Comment: Потому что компилятор производит поиск имен только в тексте текущей единицы трансляции. А правильно будет вынести объявление в заголовочный файл и включать его. А лучше сразу сделать функцию inline и определить в нем же.

Comment: Как Вы себе это представляете? Идет такой компилятор по 1.срр и видит как в `main` 
 вызываеться `foo`. И что ему делать? Ни типа функции, ни типов аргументов он не знает. Он даже не знает функция ли это. И что ему, останавливать компиляцию 1.cpp идти в 2.срр и искать там? А если у Вас миллион срр файлов? Ему искать в каждом файле?

Comment: А если эта функция в библиотеке? :)

Comment: @EOF К чему столько сарказма? Может человек раньше использовал C# какой-нибудь. Если бы в языке была несколько иная грамматика, то все вполне могло бы работать без необходимости втыкать объявления перед использованием. Даже вообще без необходимости в каких-то объявлениях.

Comment: @user7860670 Ну тут зависит от интонации) Я не намеревался вложить сарказм в мой комментарий. Если Вы или ТС так подумали, то приношу свои извинения. Не имел умысла кого-то унизить и т.п.